# Set the width and gap in geom_bar in a large dataset with a lot of unique values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the dataframe below:

```
res<-sample.int(2187, 2187)
freq<-floor(runif(2187, 95,105))
t<-data.frame(res,freq)
```

and Im trying to create a bar chart based on this but despite the fact that I use `width` and `color` arguments I still cannot create space between the bars which are black instead of the selected `fill`.

```
library(ggplot2)
require(scales)
ggplot(t,width=0.1)+
  geom_bar(aes(x=res,y=freq ,fill = (t$res==101)),
              color = "black",stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("darkblue", "lightblue"), guide = F) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16)+ theme(legend.position = "none")+
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = seq(80, 115, 5))+ scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)
```

[image]

Note that this code works nice for a dataset with much fewer unique values like:

```
fac<-factor(rep(c(80,85,100,100.5,100.7,101,101.5,110,105),2000000))
res<-data.frame(fac)
new<-data.frame(table(res))
require(scales)
ggplot(new,width=0.1)+
  geom_bar(aes(x=res,y=Freq ,fill = (new$res==101)),
              color = "black",stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("darkblue", "lightblue"), guide = F) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16)+ theme(legend.position = "none")+
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = seq(80, 115, 5))+ scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)
```

[image]

Comment: There's just too many bars to make this feasible. Why not use `geom_segment` instead to create lines?

Comment: how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be I am completely wrong but if I understand correctly, the OP wants to reproduce the second chart from scratch using a sample of random numbers instead of already tabulated counts.

To create a histogram / bar chart, we only need a vector of random numbers (wraped in a data.frame for ggplot) and let `geom_bar()` do the counting. In addition, a particular bar will be highlighted.

By using `floor()`, the random numbers are already binned but are still considered as continuous by `ggplot()`. Therefore, they need to be turned into factor.

```
# create data
set.seed(123L) # ensure random data are reproducible 
t <- data.frame(res = floor(runif(2187, 95, 105)))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(t) + 
  aes(x = as.factor(res), fill = res == 101) +
  geom_bar() +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkblue", "lightblue"), guide = FALSE) +
  xlab("res") + 
  ylab("freq")
```

[image]

#### Edit: `geom_histogram()`

Ther is an alternative approach using `geom_histogram()`.

`geom_histogram()` does all steps in one go: The binning (no need to use `floor()`) as well as counting and plotting:

```
set.seed(123L) # ensure random data are reproducible 
t2 <- data.frame(res = runif(2187, 95,105)) # floor() omitted here

ggplot(t2) + 
  aes(x = res, fill = floor(res) == 101) +
  geom_histogram(breaks = seq(95, 105, 1), closed = "left") +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkblue", "lightblue"), guide = FALSE) +
  xlab("res") + 
  ylab("freq")
```

[image]

Here, the `breaks` parameter was used to specify the bin boundaries explicitely. Alternatively, the number of bins or the width of the bins can be specifies. This gives flexibilty to play around with the parameters.

#### Edit 2

The OP [has asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58090591/set-the-width-and-gap-in-geom-bar-in-a-large-dataset-with-a-lot-of-unique-values/58092514#comment102588644_58092514) about the case where the random numbers are uniformly distributed between 100 and 1015. With an adjustment to the sequence of breaks,

```
set.seed(123L) # ensure random data are reproducible 
t3 <- data.frame(res = runif(2187, 100, 1015))

ggplot(t3) + 
  aes(x = res, fill = floor(res) == 101) +
  geom_histogram(breaks = seq(100, 1015, 1), closed = "left") +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkblue", "lightblue"), guide = FALSE) +
  xlab("res") + 
  ylab("freq")
```

returns

[image]

This chart contains over 900 bars for each bin of width 1 which aren't all visible depending on the screen resolution as already [explained by Jon Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58090998/3817004).

Therefore, it might be more suitable to reduce the number of bins, e.g., to 100 bins:

```
ggplot(t3) + 
  aes(x = res, fill = floor(res) == 101) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 100L) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkblue", "lightblue"), guide = FALSE) +
  xlab("res") + 
  ylab("freq")
```

[image]

Please note that `101` is still highlighted in the lower left corner.

Comment: thanks but what if the dataframe is like: t <- data.frame(res = floor(runif(2187, 100, 1015)))

Answer (score 0):

Edit -- added alternate solutions at bottom.

If you have over 2,000 bars, and each one has a black outline 1 pixel wide on each side, that'll take something on the order of 6,000 horizontal pixels (ignoring anti-aliasing) to see one with a different fill. Most screens have much lower resolution than that.

If you must use bars, and must show every value, one option would be to drop the outline with `color = NA` and set `width = 1` (as a term in the `geom_col`/`geom_bar` call) so there's no distracting blank space between bars. Even then, the different color at `res == 101` is only visible at certain resolutions. (That might vary on device settings and anti-aliasing.)

```
ggplot(t)+
  geom_col(aes(x=res,y=freq , fill = (res==101)),
           color = NA, width = 1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("darkblue", "lightblue"), guide = F) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(500*0:4, 101))
```

[image]

---

If you must show all 2000 points, but want to highlight one, it might make sense to use a different geom that spreads the data out to use more of the available space.

For instance, we might use `geom_point` or `geom_jitter` to plot all the coordinates in 2d space. Here, I highlight the element with `res == 101`. I use `arrange` to make sure the special dot gets plotted last so that it doesn't get occluded.

```
library(dplyr)
ggplot(t %>% arrange(res == 101), 
       aes(x = res, y = freq, 
           fill = res == 101, 
           size = res == 101)) +
  geom_jitter(shape = 21, stroke = 0.1)
```

[image]

Or we might plot the data as a line, highlighting the special dot on its own:

```
ggplot(t, aes(res, freq)) + 
  geom_line(color = "gray70") +
  geom_point(data = subset(t, res == 101)) +
  expand_limits(y=0)
```

[image]

Comment: so there is no clear way to make it more visible like in the second screenshot with the fewer values